# Telegram-cli how to handle requests through php?

Tags: telegram-bot

I do bot via telegram-cli.
Established telegram-cli on the server, everything works well.

To bot automatically posted, do so: `bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s query.lua`
Queries to the bot go to `query.lua` file.

**Here's how to make so that the requests made by the bot sent to a PHP file and processed by them?**

I watched over here https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client, but nothing has happened.

Comment: Why are you using a cli tools (it seems it uses your own contact) instead of the Telegram Bot Platform ?

Comment: There was a great need to create a bot is on the Telegram-cli, rather than bots platform. If you know how, please help :)

Comment: _Here's how to make so that the requests made by the bot sent to a PHP file and processed by them?_ Please clarify the question